# PHP Regex : Replace substring between two special character

Tags: php, regex

Updating the Question:

```
$li_text = $li->plaintext;
echo '<br>'.$li_text;
echo '<br>'.$li_text = preg_replace('/\:(.*?)\>/',':', $li_text);
```

`$li` getting the Value "Qualification : School & Graduation > BE / B.Tech ( Engineering ) " `//by using simple html DOM parsing from other websites`

The output i am getting is

```
Qualification : School & Graduation > BE / B.Tech ( Engineering )
Qualification : School & Graduation > BE / B.Tech ( Engineering )
```

If i assign `$li_text = "Qualification : School & Graduation > BE / B.Tech ( Engineering )"` then the REGEX is working fine.

Comment: Are you sure? [This seems to be working on regex101](http://www.regex101.com/r/oB1iW9).

Comment: I just tested them and they worked fine. Are you assigning the return value of `preg_replace` back into `$str`? (Had to ask; sometimes it's the simple things)

Comment: @dleiftah I think that's what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working fine. Please notice that `preg_replace` doesn't change the subject (i.e. `$str`) but returns a result.

> **preg_replace()** returns an array if the ***subject*** parameter is an array,
>   or a string otherwise.
>
> If matches are found, the new ***subject*** will be returned, otherwise
>   ***subject*** will be returned unchanged or **NULL** if an error occurred.

So:

```
preg_replace('/:(.*?)\>/',':', $str);

echo $str;
```

is **wrong**. But:

```
$str = preg_replace('/:(.*?)\>/',':', $str);

echo $str;
```

is **working**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one :

```
preg_replace('/(?<=:)(.*?)>/', '', $str);
```